# Is it possible to limit bandwidth of aws ec2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bandwidth

My AWS EC2 instance needs to transfer with an external FTP server at speeds below 64 Kbps.

Is there a way to limit the bandwidth of the outbound to a specific speed in the AWS EC instance?

Unlike physical servers, the AWS instances does not seem to work either controlling the speed of the network interface (ethtool) or using TC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS does not offer a way to limit network speeds/bandwidth at EC2 instance level. The only limitation is tied to the size of the instance and number of vCPUs, where smaller instance types have smaller bandwidth caps. But even the smallest instances support much more than the limit you need (eg: t3.nano can burst up to 5 Gbps).

Your best bet would be OS level controls or to use some sort of third-party tool.